# Currency symbols inside lstlisting

Tags: latex, lstlisting

I am trying to add a GBP \pounds symbol inside lstlisting

```
\begin{lstlisting}
Lorem ipsum 3£ \pounds
\end{lstlisting}
```

However this results in the following line:

```
Lorem ipsum 3Â \pounds
```

How do I draw correct GBP symbol inside lstlisting?

Thank you very much!

Comment: This may be better asked at http://tex.stackexchange.com. That said, LaTeX generally doesn't like it when you paste in non-ASCII symbols, but `\pounds` is definitely right. Why are you _also_ including a `£`?

Comment: escaping commands in lstlisting does not work, so the final result of \pounds is \pounds, not £.

Comment: Oh, I see - [`lstlisting`](http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/LaTeX/Packages/Listings) works like `verbatim`. Then perhaps you should use a different list environment.

Answer (score 4):

This should work even if it is a bit hackish:

```
\begin{lstlisting}[mathescape=true]
Lorem ipsum 3$\mbox{\pounds}$ \pounds
\end{lstlisting}
```

Move the question to tex.stackexchange.com and you'll have better answers wrt character encodings.

Answer (score 0):

This even works inside verbatim and using xelatex compiler:

```
\usepackage{newunicodechar}
\newunicodechar{£}{\textsterling}
```

---

```
\begin{lstlisting}
Lorem ipsum 3£
\end{lstlisting}
```

---

```
\begin{verbatim}
Lorem ipsum 3£
\end{verbatim}
```